# Selling A Car Anonymously

Tags: united-states, fees, sales-tax, transfer, title

Is it ever legal for me to sell a car to someone by just signing my name and
dating the title, such that the buyer's information is completely blank?
To be clear, the title itself is legal, clean, and in my name.

This allows the buyer to sell/transfer the car again to someone else within
the two-week window that most states allow for registering a purchased used
car.  I know dealers usually do this with other methods, but this would
be cheaper, and might be more applicable if, for example, the buyer wasn't
sure if he would register it in his name or his father's name.  Assume the
buyer gets insurance for the car, to satisfy state insurance laws, before he
drives it away.

Comment: Seems fairly common practice, at least here in Nevada.  It's certainly been the case with the cars I've bought and sold.  As for driving away, I''ve always had the seller drop it off at my house, or driven it to the purchaser's place, simply because that avoids the problem of one of us having to get a 3rd person for rides.

Answer (score -1):

In other words, *‘would it ever be legal to cheat the government out of taxes?’*
I think you know the answer to that question.

Comment: How is it "cheating" the government out of taxes?  The taxes are due when & if the car is registered.

Comment: The sales tax becomes _due_ when you buy the car. It is _collected_ when you register it.

Comment: This would be highly state dependent.

Comment: Whether there is sales tax due at all depends on which state you are in.

Comment: @Aganju: Perhaps that's so in your state.  Not here.  So if you for instance buy a car that you intend to disassemble for parts, there's no tax.